# Number of distributions of $25$ identical balls into boxes $A, B, C$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Number of distributions of $25$ identical balls into boxes $A, B, C$ if $A$ must contain at least $3$ balls $B$ must contain at least $5$ balls and $C$ must contain exactly $6$ balls?

Finding the number of balls in $A, B$ looks like this problem below:

> Find the number of distributions of a given set of identical balls into a given
>   set of distinct boxes, if no boxes are allowed to be empty.
>
> The answer to this problem is $\binom{k-1}{n-1}.$

This is what I tried below. I'd like to see how to correct it if it's all wrong.

We count the balls in $C$ first. There are $\binom{25}{6}$ balls in $C.$ Next, we start by including two balls in $A$ and consider how many ways the remaining balls can be selected. That must be $\binom{17 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{16}{2}.$ In the same way there must be $\binom{15 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{14}{4}$ balls in $B$.

I think the boxes $A, B$ are disjoint, so the answer must be $\binom{25}{6} \cdot\left( \binom{16}{2} +\binom{14}{4} \right).$

Comment: @turkeyhundt: Into two boxes.  Box $C$ must contain *exactly* six balls.

Comment: Ah yes. Deleting comment entirely as your answer covers everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simpler than that.  Six balls, and no more, go into $C$, so the remaining $19$ balls go into $A$ and $B$.  Of those $19$, at least $3$ go into $A$ and $5$ go into $B$.  That leaves $11$ that may be distributed arbitrarily amongst those two boxes.  There are $12$ ways to do so, from $(0, 11)$ to $(11, 0)$.

That's all.  If you were concerned about the *probabilities* of ending up with that kind of configuration, you'd have to break it down finer than that.  But as it is, that's all you need.

---

Incidentally, there are not $\binom{25}{6}$ balls in $C$.  There are $6$ balls in $C$.  There are $\binom{25}{6}$ ways to choose six of $25$ *distinct* balls to go into $C$, but that's not the situation you have here.  There's only one way to choose six of $25$ identical balls to go into $C$.

Comment: Suppose we absolutely want to use the formula $\binom{k-1}{n-1}.$ How would we go about that?

Comment: @ape: Conditions such as minimum number of balls and exact number of balls must be taken care of first.  You still end up with the task of placing $11$ balls into $2$ boxes, with each box containing a non-negative number; or, alternatively, $13$ balls into $2$ boxes, with each box containing a positive number.  (We place two balls into $A$ and five balls into $B$, and demand that the placement of the remaining $13$ balls put at least one into each of them.)  This latter is the one that has the formula $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.  In this case, we have $\binom{13-1}{2-1} = \binom{12}{1} = 12$.

Comment: Note: We normally have $n$ be the larger number, $k$ the smaller, so that's the way I've written it up.  But the concept is the same, no matter the names.

Comment: @ Brian Tung, I have one last question. It's a bit off-topic. What are some of the best book/websites where i can learn more about balls to bins problems? Thanks.

Comment: @ape: I can't think of anything specific offhand, but browsing through this site (Math StackExchange, that is) is usually helpful, because of the back-and-forth explanation that often happens.  So you see not only the solutions, but also common misconceptions and their clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

We must put exactly six balls in C.  So $25-6 =19$ balls that  remain.  Of these $17$ balls, we need next to consider how to distribute the balls to two boxes $A, B,\;(k=2)$, providing we have $A\geq 3,\; B\geq 5$.

This can easily be represented through use of Stars-and-Bars: $$(A+3) + (B+5) = 19 \iff A+B = 11$$

Now, we have $k=2$, $n= 11$ which gives us: $$\binom{n+k-1}{n} = \binom{12}{11} = \frac {12!}{11!(1!)}= 12$$